# How can I select a column from a list of dataframes?

Tags: r, purrr

I have several tibbles as a list column in my tibble.  it looks like

```
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  kind      data                 
  <chr>     <list>               
1 Bernoulli <tibble [3,154 × 13]>
2 Binomial  <tibble [43 × 3]>
```

Each of the tibbles in the `data` column has a column called `cigs`.  I'd like to extract that column from each tibble, and include that as a new column.  The desired output is

```
  # A tibble: 2 x 2
      kind      data                   cigs
      <chr>     <list>                 <list>
    1 Bernoulli <tibble [3,154 × 13]>  <tibble [3,154 x 1]>
    2 Binomial  <tibble [43 × 3]>      <tibble [43 x 1]>
```

Currently, I do this as

```
library(tidyverse)
compare_me %>% 
  mutate(cigs = data %>% map( ~ select(.x,cigs)) )
```

Is there an easier way to do this with purrr?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how much easier you want it to get, but here's a way with just `purrr`. You can map the `[` function (equivalent to doing `df$data["cigs"]`) and store the result in the cigs variable. No need for dplyr.

```
library(purrr)

a = tibble::tibble(r = letters, cigs = runif(26))
b = tibble::tibble(r = LETTERS, cigs = rnorm(26))

df = tibble::tibble(kind = c("bernie","binomi"),data = list(a,b))
df$cigs = map(df$data,`[`,"cigs")

#> # A tibble: 2 x 3
#>     kind              data              cigs
#>    <chr>            <list>            <list>
#> 1 bernie <tibble [26 x 2]> <tibble [26 x 1]>
#> 2 binomi <tibble [26 x 2]> <tibble [26 x 1]>
```

Comment: Looks like I can just do `mutate(cigs = map(data,'cigs'))`.  Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: When I run that it returns a vector rather than a tibble for the new cigs column which doesn't match up with your stated desired output.

Comment: Didn't notice that.  Looks like your answer is best then.